# Forecasting - Performance measures, BIAS and Mean Percentage Errors

Tags: forecasting, predictive-models, bias

I have calculated BIAs and MPE for a forecasted decompositional model, BIAS comes out as underpredicting and MPE comes out as overpredicting. Is this possible seen as they both measure how biased a forecast is?

Comment: Hi there and welcome. In the interest of your question... 1) Could you please elaborate on what BIAS (in capitals) is? 2) What do you mean by "underpredicting" and "overpredicting"? Does it mean that one is on average too high and the other on average too low? 3) Is this finding statistically significant? 4) What are your own thoughts? – *Reviewer*

Answer (score 1):

The Mean Percentage Error does *not* measure the bias. It measures a kind of "percentage bias".

Suppose you have two identical point forecasts, $\hat{y}_1 = \hat{y_2} = 100$. However, the corresponding actuals are $y_1 = 50$ and $y_2 = 150$. Your forecast is unbiased, since the mean error is zero. However, the first forecast has a percentage error of $100\%$, and the second of $-33\%$, for a mean percentage error of $33\%$.

This earlier thread concerns the Mean *Absolute* Percentage Error, but may still be helpful: [What are the shortcomings of the Mean Absolute Percentage Error (MAPE)?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/299712/1352)

Comment: Wouldn't it be -100% and 33% and then the average is 33.5 %? But doesn't this mean overall on average the forecast is underpredicting? If you have more data, this becomes a more valid measurement?

Comment: Whether it's + or - depends on how you define your error, as $y-\hat{y}$ or $\hat{y}-y$, both are common (Green & Tashman, 2008, *Foresight*). If you prefer your calculation, then you would get an MPE of -33%. I personally prefer my calculation, because with $e=\hat{y}-y$, positive errors correspond to overforecasts. And no, with more data, this will not change - just imagine repeating this pattern many times; the mean errors won't change.

Comment: Okay so what does the MPE actually show you then?

Comment: Not much. That's my point. I don't use it much.

Comment: Ahhh... Ive been asked to comment on it for my degree, this should be interesting

Comment: [The thread on the MAPE should give you some food for thought then.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/299712/1352) Good luck!